# DAX Expression to link Excel pivot table to a second table based on slicer filter values

Tags: pivot-table, powerquery, powerpivot, slicers

I am trying to link two pivot tables using DAX, without setting up a relationship first, with rows respecting a user's slicer input. I believe from a [previous answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410609/link-excel-pivot-table-to-slicer-with-many-to-many-relationship-with-powerpivot) that DAX can do this easily, but I lack the expertise in DAX and PowerPivot Measures.

I have uploaded my sample data here https://github.com/johntdata/Share/raw/master/SampleDataPivotJoin.xlsx. I don't yet have a high enough reputation to post a screenshot, but my data is pretty simple. Table1 looks like this:

```
┌──────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ Activity │ Group │ Staff Count │
├──────────┼───────┼─────────────┤
│ A1       │ A     │           3 │
│ A2       │ A     │           7 │
│ A3       │ A     │          10 │
│ B1       │ B     │           8 │
│ B2       │ B     │           9 │
│ B3       │ B     │           6 │
│ B4       │ B     │           8 │
│ C1       │ C     │          10 │
│ C2       │ C     │           2 │
```

And Table2 looks like this:

```
┌──────────┬───────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ Activity │ Group │ Category │ Income │
├──────────┼───────┼──────────┼────────┤
│ A1       │ A     │ Apple    │     15 │
│ A1       │ A     │ Pear     │      9 │
│ A1       │ A     │ Banana   │     27 │
│ A2       │ A     │ Apple    │      3 │
│ A2       │ A     │ Pear     │     47 │
│ A2       │ A     │ Banana   │     54 │
│ A3       │ A     │ Apple    │     41 │
│ A3       │ A     │ Pear     │     10 │
```

With a slicer on Group, I want to 'combine' the data on the Activity field in order to see sum of Staff Count from Table1 along with the % of Income types from Table2 (with %s expressed as a total of the row). The combined result might look like this:

```
┌────────────┬────────────────────┬───────┬────────┬──────┐
│ Row Labels │ Sum of Staff Count │ Apple │ Banana │ Pear │
├────────────┼────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼──────┤
│ A1         │                  3 │ 29%   │ 53%    │ 18%  │
│ A2         │                  7 │ 3%    │ 52%    │ 45%  │
│ A3         │                 10 │ 71%   │ 12%    │ 17%  │
│ B1         │                  8 │ 46%   │ 24%    │ 30%  │
│ B2         │                  9 │ 14%   │ 81%    │ 5%   │
│ B3         │                  6 │ 9%    │ 46%    │ 45%  │
│ B4         │                  8 │ 8%    │ 40%    │ 52%  │
│ C1         │                 10 │ 18%   │ 27%    │ 55%  │
└────────────┴────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴──────┘
```

It would be excessively cumbersome to wrangle my input data into a single table, so I'm hoping to use DAX to join the two tables whilst respecting a slicer on Group from Table1.

I want the user to be able to select one or more Groups using a slicer button. What DAX measure will allow me to do this please? The example above is generic, but the principle will be really useful for lots of my projects.

Comment: There are a number of challenges you have here. Using relationships would be recommended here but not essential. Any reason to avoid using relationships? The second bigger challenge is having your pivot table columns show Staff Count and one per category (Fruit). There are two options for this one, creating a measure for each column value (Staff Count, Apple, Banana, Pear etc...) or creating a new table with these headers, and having a dynamic measure that returns the value based on the header.

Comment: Thanks @SamNseir - re relationships, only that I've seen them slow down slicer performance in the past, but perhaps that wouldn't be the case here. Perhaps a dynamic measure might work better as I would have dozens of categories instead of just three fruits in this example. I wondered if having the fruit category in columns would force the sum of staff count to repeat itself multiple times, but then figured there'd be a way to get around that in DAX